# Angular 6 Material matdatePicker with floatLabel on form field

Tags: angular, date, input, angular-material

I believe I found a bug in Angular Materials input component when using `[matDatePicker]` and have created a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ayzxhr?file=app/datepicker-overview-example.html).

When having using the `[matDatePicker]` as well as using `[floatLabel]` on the `mat-form-field` it seems that there is a problem. When the user goes to type in the field instead of clicking and choosing from the datepicker the text will go over top of the label or placeholder text for the input field

[image]

Comment: Which browser? Seems OK in Chrome I think **EDIT** I've just seen it's only when you type letters first

Comment: Seems like a validation error should have been displayed, if the input is gibberish or not in a format understood by Date Picker. If you enter a valid in `short` or `long` format it works fine. So when there is gibberish, I suspect there should be a way to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem like some kind of bug, as noted in the comments by Andrew Lobban. You should report it at https://github.com/angular/material2/issues.

As a workaround, you can use mat-placeholder with ngIf:

```
<mat-form-field [floatLabel]="'never'">
  <mat-placeholder *ngIf="!input.value">Choose a date</mat-placeholder>
  <input #input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks I will submit that issue to github. Your workaround works.